# Extracting fields from json

Tags: python, json, pandas

```
"Repo": {
    "D_Repo": {
        "fields": [
            {
                "Out": " ",
                "number": {
                    "Bks": "[number is valid]",
                    "Ban": "[VALID]"
                },
                "st_ID": 2
                "sign": "No Match"
            }
        ],
        "RID": 2546,
        "result": "OK"
    }
```

I have read the json using pd.read_json and Repo is a column in a dataframe. So how to access nested columns "bks, Ban, Out, RID and Decision" and like this there are 70 records inside "info". In above code I have displayed only one record. Can anybody help out with logic and code snippet?

Comment: I want these columns "bks , Ban , Out , RID and Decision" for all 70 records. Basically i want to flatten everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this helps!!   (assuming d is what you have)

```
   d = {"Repo": {
        "DE_Repo": {
            "info": [
                {
                    "Out": " ",
                    "Value": {
                        "Bks": "[number is valid]",
                        "Ban": "[VALID]"
                    },
                    "ID": 2,
                    "Remark": "No Match"
                },
                {
                    "Out": " ",
                    "Value": {
                        "Bks": "[number is valid]",
                        "Ban": "[VALID]"
                    },
                    "ID": 2,
                    "Remark": "No Match"
                }
            ],
            "RID": 2546,
            "Decision": "Approved"
        }}}


repo_data = d['Repo']['DE_Repo']

values = []



 for keys, val in repo_data.items():
    if type(val) == list:
        for i in range(len(val)):
            for key,data in val[i].items():
                if type(data) == dict:
                    for subKey, subValue in data.items():
                        values.append([subKey,subValue])
                else:
                    values.append([key,data])
    else:
        values.append([keys,val])





extracted_points = pd.DataFrame(values,columns=['Key','Value'])
```

Output

```
           0                  1
0        Out                   
1        Bks  [number is valid]
2        Ban            [VALID]
3         ID                  2
4     Remark           No Match
5        Out                   
6        Bks  [number is valid]
7        Ban            [VALID]
8         ID                  2
9     Remark           No Match
10       RID               2546
11  Decision           Approved
```

Comment: Yeah you almost got it bro but this is for 1 main record what if there are 10 records then how to iterate it

Comment: you talking about multiple repos or de_repo or info.. ?

Comment: Just use a standard loop : suppose you have multiple entries in d, then
for i in d:
    repo_data = i['Repo']['DE_Repo']
   .... and then continue the above stuff

Comment: info bro ...if there are 70 info

Comment: it is iterating correctly over 8 records but inside info there are 70 records so it is taking only one record

Comment: ooh for that please modify the val[0] thing because there i am assuming only one record.. wait updating see if that works..

Comment: Thankyou so much bro ..got the output as expected .

Comment: how to sort by 8 records in dataframe...its showing 1700 rows

Comment: depends.. how do you want to display the info data.(since it has over 70 in it)..?

Comment: consider above repo is 1 and there are 8 repo in total

Comment: the above code will extract all data for repo1 and similarly for 8 repo what changes do i need to do....so that it can store in dataframe in 8 rows

Comment: can anybody tell me how to write method for this ?